# date_add procedure with repeat loop

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

Why is this procedure not working?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `incDate`;

CREATE PROCEDURE incDate(@fromdate date, @enddate date)

REPEAT
  SET @fromdate = date_add(@fromdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  INSERT INTO `dentists`.`dayT` (`day`) VALUES (@fromdate);
UNTIL @fromdate > @enddate END REPEAT;

END
```

MySQL just gives this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@fromdate date, @enddate date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `BEGIN` statement. Try this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `incDate`;

CREATE PROCEDURE incDate(@fromdate date, @enddate date)

BEGIN

REPEAT
  SET @fromdate = date_add(@fromdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  INSERT INTO `dentists`.`dayT` (`day`) VALUES (@fromdate);
UNTIL @fromdate > @enddate END REPEAT;

END
```